# Finding the form of this holonomic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, exponential-function

I am looking for the exponential function that describes the following behavior:

Start at the value `1`. The next value of the sequence is calculated by the following formula:

```
Value of Previous + Value of Previous * (1/3)
```

The idea is that this is experience in a video game, where each level is harder to obtain than the last. Meaning the sequence would be:

```
1, 4/3, 16/9, 64/27 ...
```

After starring at this for so long, I couldn't think the equation to do it. It obviously needs to be an exponential function but I thought for sure I'd need to write `1/3` somewhere in the correct form.

The actual answer to this is `(3/4)^(1-n)` but I do not understand how I could have came to that conclusion if I didn't use [Wolfram Alpha's Pattern Finder](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=d9976f1c2c0c972d1cee0c3647cbd194).

How can this be solved? I have to approach these kind of patterns all the time in my programming works and I rely on the Wolfram tool far too often.

Comment: Where did you take the word "holonomic" from? What you want is "recursive" - "holonomic" means a totally unrelated thing.

Comment: @AlexM. when you use Wolfram Alpha's Pattern calculator, if it cannot find a function that matches your series then it says "No holonomic function exists that matches your data". I assumed this means that I am looking for a holonomic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_{n-1}$ be the previous number.  Then,

$$x_n=x_{n-1}+\frac13x_{n-1}=\frac43x_{n-1}$$

We then know this is in [geometric progression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), so $x_n=x_0\times\left(\frac43\right)^n$.

If you did not see this, my first attempt would be to write out the first few terms to see if you can spot a pattern.  Once you think you have the right formula, you can use [induction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to verify your results.

Or, since you knew the result should be an exponential function, you could try substitution:

$$x_n=b^n\implies b^n=\frac43b^{n-1}$$

Divide both sides by $b^{n-1}$, you will find that $b=\frac43$.

Comment: Also note that $$(3/4)^{1-n}=x_0(4/3)^n$$where $x_0=3/4$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence as $a_n$.

Notice 
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac13 a_{n-1}=(\frac43)^1 a_{n-1}=(\frac43)^2a_{n-2}=\cdots=(\frac43)^{n-1}a_1$$

Given $a_1=1$ and recall that $\displaystyle a^{-b}=(\frac1a)^b$, we have
$$a_n=(\frac43)^{n-1}(1)=(\frac34)^{1-n}$$